# Docker-Compose LSP will not attach to buffer nor automatically start

Tags: neovim, lsp

With the current default configuration of the "docker_compose_language_service" LSP, it will not start, nor attach after being started to the current buffer.

When taking a look at the configuration here: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#docker_compose_language_service

I noticed that the file type is, "yaml.docker-compose". However docker-compose files are usually postfixed with either .yaml or .yml so the filetype will never be detected as such.

The way I got around this is running  `:setfiletype yaml.docker-compose`
and then the LSP would behave normally. The first solution I thought was to change the filetypes from the setup to .yaml and .yml but I don't think that's the right approach.

In my neovim configuration, I now have this in my options.lua to automatically run this depending on whether the file is named, "docker-compose.yaml".

```
function docker_fix()
    local filename = vim.fn.expand("%:t")

    if filename == "docker-compose.yaml" then
        vim.bo.filetype = "yaml.docker-compose"
        print("matched!")
    else
        print(filename)
    end
end

vim.cmd[[au BufRead * lua docker_fix()]]
```

I don't think this normal behavior. Is having the filetype, "yaml.docker-compose" intended  or is there something wrong with my working environment? The only other thing I can think of is that the current working directory does have a docker-compose.yaml (and of course it would, I'm working on that exact file!) and it doesn't pick up the current_dir as the root_dir.

If anyone could give me a clue or insight, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: I believe  your solution is the good one. `filetype` and file extension are not supposed to be the same. The `yaml.docker-compose` is a combined `filetype` that trigger the `yaml` `filetype` extensions and the `docker-compose` `filetype`  extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your solution is the good one.

Remark: `filetype` and file extension are not supposed to be the same.

The `yaml.docker-compose` is a combined `filetype` that triggers both the `yaml` `filetype` extensions and the `docker-compose` `filetype`  extension.